# Cant install custom package in Google Colab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, python-packaging

i have a custom package written by myself called deblurrer, it is a bunch of script for train a neural network.

In Google Colab, i cloned my repo successfully, i have all the required stuff for execute the setup.py module and install deblurrer 1.0.0. When i install deblurrer locally in my pc, everything works as expected, but when i try to run `!python setup.py install` in Colab, nothing is installed, in fact, the output says everything is fine, but i cant import the package. Execute the next code in two separate Colab Cells for reproduce the issue:

```
# Cell 01
# Executes the cell in bash mode
%%bash

git clone https://github.com/ElPapi42/deep-deblurring
python deep-deblurring/setup.py install
```

```
# Cell 02
import deblurrer
```

as you can see, the installation runs as espected, but when importing:`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'deblurrer'`

What can be wrong?

Comment: maybe you have to use different python - ie. `python3` or `python3.7` ? You could check `python -V` to see if it is not Python 2

Comment: I double check, actually Google Colab uses Python 3.6

Comment: system may have installed many different versions of Python and you may install module for one version but Colab may uses different version to run code. Every version use own modules. Try to install using `python3.6`  - `!python3.6 setup.py install`

Comment: hello! i install using ```python3.6 deep-deblurring/setup.py install``` and the package is installed, but when imported still not working, says module not found

Comment: check `import sys` `print( sys.executable )` - maybe it doesn't use `3.6` but `3.5` or `3.7` or something else.

Comment: it returns ```/usr/bin/python3``` when do ```print(sys.executable)```

Comment: so try `!/usr/bin/python3 setup.py install`

Comment: No luck :( same errors, maybe this a problem of Colab, but not sure how this can happen, there is no sense in this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to take a slightly different approach with Colab.

```
# 1. Download the repo and set it as the current directory
!git clone https://github.com/ElPapi42/deep-deblurring
%cd deep-deblurring

# 2. install the project/module
!python setup.py install

# 3. Add the project directory to the path
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())

#4. Run your code
# ....
```

As outlined here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53747334/2466781